# Reading line by line in perl

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Suppose I have a text file with the following format

```
@ATDGGSGDTSG
NTCCCCC
+
@nddhdhnadn
@ATDGGSGDTSG
NTCCCCC
+
nddhdhnadn
```

Now its a repeating pattern of "4" lines and I every time want to print only the 2nd line i.e. the line after the line starting with "@" i.e 2nd line..6th line..etc.

How can I do it?

Comment: And yet another crosspost. http://askubuntu.com/questions/362959/reading-a-file-line-by-line/362997#362997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR%4==2' a
NTCCCCC
NTCCCCC
```

`NR` stands for number or record, in this case being number of line. Then, if we divide it by 4, we get all lines whose modulus is 2.

---

#### Update on your comment

> And wat if I want the output to be > "nextline" NTCCCCC > "nextline"
>   NTCCCCC i.e. I want to add ">" before that line while redirecting the
>   output.

This way, for example:

```
$ awk 'NR%4==2 {print ">"; print $0}' a
>
NTCCCCC
>
NTCCCCC
```

---

Another example:

```
$ seq 30 | awk 'NR%4==2' 
2
6
10
14
18
22
26
30
```

Comment: And wat if I want the output to be 
> "nextline"
NTCCCCC
> "nextline"
NTCCCCC

i.e. I want to add ">" before that line while redirecting the output.

Comment: Mmmm why the downvote? Also, @GauravChetal for future questions try to improve your description. If you say "every 2nd, 6th... line" but what you really want is "every line after @", then say it.

Comment: Sir now if I want to say print the first line then I will have to use "N%4=1" and I wanted to print both first and 2nd line so I pipelined them saying "awk 'NR%4==1 {print $0}' check.fastq|awk 'NR%4==2 {print $0}' check.fastq" but it is not working..(I wanted the output to be like -- ">firstline(newline)secondline(newline)>>firstline(newline)secondline(newline)). Sorry if I dint explain it well.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question making sure what you ask is what you want. This will avoid us updating our answers every time. To do what you need you may use `awk 'NR%4==1 || NR%4==2' file`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne 'print if $b and !/^@/; $b=/^@/' file
```

Comment: I have edited the question and suppose there is an "@" in the starting of the third line also. Then how will it happen

Comment: Nice solution. @GauravChetal this one will print the line next after a `@` line, and not just the 2nd, 6th etc line

Comment: @mpapec : Sir I am extremely sorry.I gave acceptance but it is showing  -2 I dont know why.Can you help.

Comment: @GauravChetal if your lines begin with `@` then output should be two lines with `NTCCCCC`. Use `perl -ne 'print if $b and !/@/; $b=/@/' file` if `@` is not first char in the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^\@/{getline;print}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable like `$printNextLine` and loop over all your Input, Setting it to `1` whenever you see a line with @ and printing the current line while Setting the variable back to `0` if it is `1`.

Not as effective and short as the other answers but maybe more intuitive for someone new to perl.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^\@/{getline;print}' file
```